# How to remove multiple documents in Doctrine MongoDB ODM

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-odm

How can I remove multiple documents in doctrine mongodb odm? In PHP class I should be able to do it using the following code:

```
 $db->collection->remove(array("age" => 18));
```

How can I do it in doctrine mongo odm?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have two options. Using the DocumentManager, you can request the collection for a given class. This will actually return a `Doctrine\MongoDB\Collection` instance, which wraps the base `MongoCollection` to support logging and events. The underlying `MongoCollection` is available if you really want it, too:

```
$collection = $dm->getDocumentCollection('Documents\User');
$collection->remove(array('age' => 18));

// Use the raw MongoCollection to bypass logging and events
$mongoCollection = $collection->getMongoCollection();
$mongoCollection->remove(array('age' => 18));
```

Alternatively, you can use the [query builder API](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html):

```
$qb = $dm->createQueryBuilder('Documents\User');
$qb->remove()
    ->field('age')->equals(18)
    ->getQuery()
    ->execute();
```

If you stop at `getQuery()`, you can use the `debug()` method on the returned query object to see what Doctrine will execute against the database.

Comment: I haven't found the first option in the documentation, It has small code as I wanted. Thank you!